# Shouldn't we have a close reason on meta 'covered by the FAQ'?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, meta

Upon looking at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/what-privileges-are-given-to-a-1000-reputation-member-of-stack-overflow) question, it occurred to me: Shouldn't we have a close reason - 'covered by the FAQ'?

As there is not really any other reason to close questions like this, and those kind of questions can be seen as noise (IMHO) so it should be possible to close them.

Comment: Only if when it is closed for that reason it kills the person who asked it.

Comment: @Rich B: Any suggestions on how to implement that?

Comment: How about some exclamation marks?!?!!!!!111!

Comment: I still like the *being noise* close reason more, but this one would be an improvement, too. +1

Comment: I have long advocated a 'blatantly stupid' close reason as well.

Comment: Paying off: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/whats-the-focus-here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or make do with what's already there.

Close as duplicate pointing right to the FAQ.

And then when the Community User comes along to insert the duplicate link, go in and edit with:

> ## Covered by the FAQ
>
> link to FAQ

Comment: The problem is: you can not close as exact duplicate and point to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq. That close reason needs a specific question number.

Comment: But most of the time there is a corresponding FAQ post on Meta that happens to be quite long and quite the upvoted morsel. Doesn't work in those instances outside though.

Comment: True, but this question is for those other times... ;-)

Comment: Perhaps someone should ask the question "Where can I find the FAQ?", and then we can link to that. :)

Comment: ベレアー アダム: Done -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq

Comment: @$: nice... already used it to vote to close the question in question ;-)