# what's the focus here?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

I see questions on a wide range of technologies, but for all of them generally there are focused communities dedicated to their topic/technology.

So what's the focus/purpose of this site? Or is it intentionally "any thing goes"?

Comment: There's a link to the FAQ at the very top of the screen.

Comment: Not intending to blast a noob or anything, but this isn't a programming related question. You may want to close it before you start getting down voted and whatnot.

Comment: That question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq is already coming in handy!

Answer (score 3):

Questions from people, answers from people, about programming.

You don't have to be a programmer by trade, or even know anything but VBA, SO is there for you :)

Comment: I agree with "You don't have to be a programmer by trade..." but anyone who programs, in my opinion, can be called a programmer.  (Even in VBA! ;))

Comment: Very true, but Rich had already nicked the `programmer` angle :P

Answer (score 2):

Questions from programmers, answers from programmers, about programming.

Answer (score 1):

> I see questions on a wide range of technologies - - but for all of them generally there are focused communities dedicated to their topic/technology.

I could join a HTML forum, a CSS forum, a JavaScript forum, a Flash forum, a PHP forum... (and then keep track of it all!)

... or I could just go to StackOverflow, which has a large userbase in each technology, as well as the best Q&A software I've come across thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Questions from students doing their homework, answered by students procrastinating ;-)